# de Rham cohomology of dual abelian variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, de-rham-cohomology, abelian-varieties

Suppose $X$ is an abelian variety over a field $k$. Consider the de Rham cohomology of $X^{\vee}$ (denoted by $H_{dR}^i(X^{\vee})$). I want to ask is $H_{dR}^i(X^{\vee})$ naturally dual to $H_{dR}^i(X)$?